# Accessing same named list elements of the list of lists in R

Tags: r

Frequently I encounter situations where I need to create a lot of similar models for different variables. Usually I dump them into the list. Here is the example of dummy code:

```
modlist <- lapply(1:10,function(l) {
   data <- data.frame(Y=rnorm(10),X=rnorm(10))
   lm(Y~.,data=data)
})
```

Now getting the fit for example is very easy:

```
lapply(modlist,predict)
```

What I want to do sometimes is to extract one element from the list. The obvious way is

```
sapply(modlist,function(l)l$rank)
```

This does what I want, but I wonder if there is a shorter way to get the same result?

Comment: your sample code returns an error when using the foreach package.

Comment: @Joris, it is a dummy code, it should not work in principle, since `simulate` is not defined. However there was an error with capitalized `C`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I see. However, people will assume your dummy code runs, and a minimal reproducible example is in general a small effort to make for illustration of a problem. It avoids we have to make one ourselves in looking for an answer.

Comment: @Joris, now the code should run. I do not know why I felt there was no need for working code in this case. The code should always work, dummy or no dummy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I usually use [kohske way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935673/accessing-same-named-list-elements-of-the-list-of-lists-in-r/5936077#5936077), but here is another trick:

```
 sapply(modlist, with, rank)
```

It is more useful when you need more elements, e.g.:

```
 sapply(modlist, with, c(rank, df.residual))
```

As I remember I stole it from hadley (from plyr documentation I think).

Main difference between `[[` and `with` solutions is in case missing elements. `[[` returns `NULL` when element is missing. `with` throw an error **unless there exist an object in global workspace having same name as searched element**. So e.g.:

```
dah <- 1
lapply(modlist, with, dah)
```

returns list of ones when `modlist` don't have any `dah` element.

Comment: thanks, this certainly feels like @hadley code, simple and elegant.

Comment: @mpiktas Main diffrence between `"[["` and `with` solutions is in case missing elements. `"[["` returns `NULL` when element is missing. `with` throw an error **unless there exist an object in global workspace having same name as searched element**. So e.g. `dah<-1;lapply(modlist, with, dah)` return list of ones when `modlist` don't have any `dah` element.

Comment: thanks for additional comment. In my case the elements in the list should not have any missing elements, so errors are welcome.

Answer (score 29):

probably these are a little bit simple:

```
> z <- list(list(a=1, b=2), list(a=3, b=4))
> sapply(z, `[[`, "b")
[1] 2 4
> sapply(z, get, x="b")
[1] 2 4
```

and you can define a function like:

```
> `%c%` <- function(x, n)sapply(x, `[[`, n)
> z %c% "b"
[1] 2 4
```

and also this looks like an extension of `$`:

```
> `%$%` <- function(x, n) sapply(x, `[[`, as.character(as.list(match.call())$n))
> z%$%b
[1] 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured something like that should be possible. It is a pity I cannot accept both answers, I picked @Marek answer purely for aesthetic reasons. I've upvoted yours.

Answer (score 1):

With Hadley's new [lowliner](https://github.com/hadley/lowliner) package you can supply `map()` with a numeric index or an element name to elegantly pluck components out of a list. `map()` is the equivalent of `lapply()` with some extra tricks.

```
library("lowliner")

l <- list(
  list(a = 1, b = 2),
  list(a = 3, b = 4)
)

map(l, "b")
map(l, 2)
```

There is also a version that simplifies the result to a vector

```
map_v(l, "a")
map_v(l, 1)
```

Comment: Update: `lowliner` is now the `purrr` package. And the `map_v` are deprecated. But you could simplify to a vectors using `map(l, "a") %>% as_vector()`