# R: It's a named list but indexing by $name doesn't work?

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn R but I'm having problems understanding these data structures. I was under the impression that named lists were indexed by 
'listName$index', but there seems to be some other form of named list. Look at the following example

```
> m <- mongo(collection = "games", db = "games")
> someGame = m$find(someQuery)

> typeof(someGame)
[1] "list"
> typeof(someGame$players)
[1] "list"

> someGame$players
  benchmarks.tower_damage.raw benchmarks.tower_damage.pct kills_per_min
1                           0                   0.0608506            NA
2                         105                   0.2522049    0.07380074
3                        1977                   0.7609042    0.33210332
4                        2042                   0.9973893    0.07380074
```

So someGame is a named list, so we can access someGame$players. But that is also a list. But attemtping someGame$players$kills_per_min, or someGame$players['kills_per_min'] just returns NULL.

So how do I access for example 'kills_per_min'?

dput output:

```
> dput(someGame$players)
list(structure(list(match_id = c(10216L, 10216L, 10216L, 10216L
), player_slot = c(0L, 1L, 128L, 129L), account_id = c(86480929L, 
86480927L, 86480949L, 86502042L), assists = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 5L), 
    deaths = c(4L, 7L, 1L, 2L), denies = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 20L), 
    gold = c(374L, 697L, 412L, 2408L), gold_per_min = c(186L, 
    217L, 401L, 319L), gold_spent = c(4324L, 4825L, 10865L, 6488L
    ), hero_damage = c(1270L, 2494L, 9157L, 4108L), hero_healing = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), hero_id = c(6L, 20L, 15L, 26L), item_0 = c(0L, 
    0L, 29L, 23L), item_1 = c(0L, 0L, 125L, 29L), item_2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 41L, 10L), item_3 = c(0L, 0L, 162L, 104L), item_4 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 16L), item_5 = c(0L, 0L, 22L, 0L), kills = c(0L, 
    2L, 9L, 2L), last_hits = c(36L, 31L, 73L, 64L), leaver_status = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), level = c(9L, 11L, 14L, 14L), tower_damage = c(0L, 
    105L, 1977L, 2042L), xp_per_min = c(176L, 241L, 431L, 388L
    ), personaname = c("dotatournament", "dotatournament", "dotatournament", 
    "dotatournament"), radiant_win = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), start_time = c(1313270783L, 1313270783L, 1313270783L, 
    1313270783L), duration = c(1626L, 1626L, 1626L, 1626L), cluster = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), lobby_type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), game_mode = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), patch = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), isRadiant = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), win = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), lose = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L), total_gold = c(5040L, 5880L, 10867L, 8644L), 
    total_xp = c(4769L, 6531L, 11680L, 10514L), kda = c(0L, 0L, 
    5L, 2L), abandons = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), benchmarks = structure(list(
        gold_per_min = structure(list(raw = c(186L, 217L, 401L, 
        319L), pct = c(0.019338422, 0.124976543, 0.525310411, 
        0.635813457)), .Names = c("raw", "pct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        4L)), xp_per_min = structure(list(raw = c(176L, 241L, 
        431L, 388L), pct = c(0.032788077, 0.14374179, 0.478828399, 
        0.653969384)), .Names = c("raw", "pct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        4L)), kills_per_min = structure(list(raw = c(0, 0.073800738, 
        0.332103321, 0.073800738), pct = c(0.059764432, 0.443610433, 
        0.897738133, 0.311854753)), .Names = c("raw", "pct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        4L)), last_hits_per_min = structure(list(raw = c(1.328413284, 
        1.143911439, 2.693726937, 2.361623616), pct = c(0.056347244, 
        0.490335898, 0.430710417, 0.973774772)), .Names = c("raw", 
        "pct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L)), 
        hero_damage_per_min = structure(list(raw = c(46.863468635, 
        92.029520295, 337.896678967, 151.586715867), pct = c(0.027991857, 
        0.124225934, 0.641605607, 0.419247656)), .Names = c("raw", 
        "pct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L)), 
        hero_healing_per_min = structure(list(raw = c(0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L), pct = c(0.989966555, 0.839744793, 0.848677923, 
        0.8167794)), .Names = c("raw", "pct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        4L)), tower_damage = structure(list(raw = c(0L, 105L, 
        1977L, 2042L), pct = c(0.0608506, 0.252204916, 0.760904171, 
        0.997389344)), .Names = c("raw", "pct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        4L))), .Names = c("gold_per_min", "xp_per_min", "kills_per_min", 
    "last_hits_per_min", "hero_damage_per_min", "hero_healing_per_min", 
    "tower_damage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    4L)), kills_per_min = c(NA, 0.073800738, 0.332103321, 0.073800738
    )), .Names = c("match_id", "player_slot", "account_id", "assists", 
"deaths", "denies", "gold", "gold_per_min", "gold_spent", "hero_damage", 
"hero_healing", "hero_id", "item_0", "item_1", "item_2", "item_3", 
"item_4", "item_5", "kills", "last_hits", "leaver_status", "level", 
"tower_damage", "xp_per_min", "personaname", "radiant_win", "start_time", 
"duration", "cluster", "lobby_type", "game_mode", "patch", "isRadiant", 
"win", "lose", "total_gold", "total_xp", "kda", "abandons", "benchmarks", 
"kills_per_min"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L)))
```

Comment: `NULL` is usually what you get when you try to reach a column that doesn't exist. Are you sure you haven't made a typo in the name of the column ?

Comment: You can learn more about accessing lists from the examples listed below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935673/accessing-same-named-list-elements-of-the-list-of-lists-in-r

Comment: `typeof()` isn't really helpful when it comes to predicting behavior. Use `class()` to find out how an object will behave. Objects can define their own methods for the `$` operator if they want. It would be useful to share the result of `dput(someGame$players)`.

Comment: `someGames$players$kills_per_min` *should* work if it's a normal list. You could also try `someGames[["players"]]$kills_per_min`.

Comment: class(someGame$players) returns "list". I swear to god the exact command someGame$players$kills_per_min returns NULL. But the printout is exactly that of the original post.

Comment: `someGame$players[[1]]$kills_per_min`